# How do I install Django notification?

Tags: python, django, installation

https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification

It doesn't say anything about installing.

How do I import it? What do I put it inside the INSTALLED_APPS, because django.notification doesn't work.?

Ok, it's inside my site-packages as "django_notification-0.2a1.dev4-py2.6.egg "

How do I import this into my views.py and also my settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look inside the .egg, you'll see that the package is called "notification".

Comment: Yes, I put it in installed_apps already. How do I import it in views.py?

Comment: Look in the .egg and see what modules that package contains. Then import them.

Answer (score 2):

Ignacio's answer is confusing. (I spent 20 minutes messing with the [notification package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notification)). Kedar's answer is better but still confusing. Here's the simplest way I installed and started using [django-notification](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-notification):

```
pip install django-notification
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'notification',
    ...
)
```

views.py:

```
from notification import models as notification

notification.send([user], 'notice_type_label', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just download notification package.
2. go to path where does it get downloaded.
3. Its needed to install which can be done in following ways :

   `$ pip install django-notification`
   or

   `easy_install django-notification`
   or

   `python setup.py install`

   Now your notification package will get installed
4. Add notification in your INSTALLED_APPS
   e.g.
   `INSTALLED_APPS = ('',
   '',...,
   'notification')`

Answer (score -1):

you can use this package

```
pip install django-notifications-hq
```

from:
https://pypi.org/project/django-notifications-hq/